# Find Operating System from ip in Python

Tags: python, networking, operating-system, ip-address

Using python, is it possible to find the operating system of a remote computer with their ip? I have already made a pinging program to locate all live ip addresses. If this is possible, how do I do this?

If you require any other information, comment and I will add whatever I can

Comment: With *just* the IP? You'd need more information than just the IP.

Comment: what information would I require?

Comment: Not easily or reliably, and not without communicating with the remote computer. Why not just get Nmap?

Comment: You should investigate NMAP. I'm not sure on the specifics, I know just enough to know that you'd need more than an IP to fingerprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly, no.

However, if there are some visible services they will usually return a short information string. By comparing these information strings you can often make an informed guess about the host system.

It's likely to be a lot of work gathering enough information to make this reliable; I suggest looking at [nmap](http://nmap.org/) (or [python-nmap](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/)) which has already done this.